# How to deploy Flask app with Vue.js frontend to AWS Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Flask app with Vue.js frontend. I can't figure out how to make AWS executing my command to install NPM modules like "npm run build".

Comment: Some discussion here ~ https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/6cc9jm/id_like_deploy_the_backend_to_elastic_beanstalk/

Comment: @Phil thanks but unfortunately this thread doesn't give any clue. I found I should probably add .ebextensions folder and configure it but so far it's not working.